# webgl why I get errors when I use version 300 in shaders

Tags: shader, webgl2

I am making webgl app. I want to use version 300 es in my shader, I am sure that browser supports this version but I get some errors when I try to use.

This is my code.

```
var VertexShaderCode = `
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    in vec3 vertexPos;
    uniform vec2 orthoValues;
    in vec2 offset;
    mat4 curProjMat=mat4(vec4(0.0),vec4(0.0),0.0,0.0,-0.05,0.0,-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);

    void main(void) {
      curProjMat[0][0] = 2.0  /  orthoValues.x;
      curProjMat[1][1] = -2.0  / orthoValues.y;
      gl_Position= curProjMat*vec4(vertexPos.x+offset.x, vertexPos.y+offset.y, 1.0, 1.0);
    }`
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, VertexShaderCode)
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader)

    var FragmentShaderCode = 
     `#version 300 es
      precision lowp float;
      out vec4 outColor;

      void main() {
        outColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
      }
     `


    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, FragmentShaderCode)
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)
    var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram)
    return shaderProgram
```

Then I assign this shader in constructor.

```
  gl.useProgram(this.Program2D)
  this.P2DvertexPos = gl.getAttribLocation(this.Program2D, 'vertexPos')
  this.P2DoffsetLoc=gl.getAttribLocation(this.Program2D, 'offset')
  this.P2DOrtoValues = gl.getUniformLocation(this.Program2D, 'orthoValues')
```

as soon as I assign this, I get these errors.

```
INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
`INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked`
INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: I get these errors.

-WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid

-getAttribLocation: program not linked

-INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked

-WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked

Comment: read the program and shader info logs using `getProgramInfoLog` and `getShaderInfoLog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling shaders and linking programs you should check if things were successful and if not then print the errors.

For shaders after you compile a shader you call

```
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  // there was an error
  console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
 ...
```

for programs after you link the program you call

```
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  // there was an error
  console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
 ...
```

Adding that you start getting told what the problems are

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
if (!gl) alert('need webgl2');

var VertexShaderCode = `
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    in vec3 vertexPos;
    uniform vec2 orthoValues;
    in vec2 offset;
    mat4 curProjMat=mat4(vec4(0.0),vec4(0.0),0.0,0.0,-0.05,0.0,-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);

    void main(void) {
      curProjMat[0][0] = 2.0  /  orthoValues.x;
      curProjMat[1][1] = -2.0  / orthoValues.y;
      gl_Position= curProjMat*vec4(vertexPos.x+offset.x, vertexPos.y+offset.y, 1.0, 1.0);
    }`
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, VertexShaderCode)
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader)
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      // there was an error
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    }

    var FragmentShaderCode = 
     `#version 300 es
      precision lowp float;
      out vec4 outColor;

      void main() {
        outColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
      }
     `


    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, FragmentShaderCode)
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      // there was an error
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    }
    
    
    var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram)
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      // there was an error
      console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    }
    
//    return shaderProgram
```

Once you do that it will tell you  `#version 300 es` is required to be the first line but for your vertex shader it was not the first line, there was a blank line before it.

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
if (!gl) alert('need webgl2');

var VertexShaderCode = `#version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    in vec3 vertexPos;
    uniform vec2 orthoValues;
    in vec2 offset;
    mat4 curProjMat=mat4(vec4(0.0),vec4(0.0),0.0,0.0,-0.05,0.0,-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);

    void main(void) {
      curProjMat[0][0] = 2.0  /  orthoValues.x;
      curProjMat[1][1] = -2.0  / orthoValues.y;
      gl_Position= curProjMat*vec4(vertexPos.x+offset.x, vertexPos.y+offset.y, 1.0, 1.0);
    }`
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, VertexShaderCode)
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader)
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      // there was an error
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    }

    var FragmentShaderCode = 
     `#version 300 es
      precision lowp float;
      out vec4 outColor;

      void main() {
        outColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
      }
     `


    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, FragmentShaderCode)
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      // there was an error
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    }
    
    
    var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram)
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      // there was an error
      console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    }
    
//    return shaderProgram
```

You might find [these articles](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) useful. They cover checking for errors in the very first article. It's surprising wherever you learned this wasn't one of the first things covered.